# select latest duplicate record from table MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, mysql-workbench

This is my sample tables:

**Table1:**

```
ID        Runnum    Thickness          Date

1          2           1.23             1/8/2015

2          2           2.32             1/9/2015

3          3           2.21             1/9/2015

4          4           3.12             1/8/2015
```

**Table2** :

```
ID        Runnum    Insitu             

1          2           1.23             

2          3           2.32             

3          4           2.21             

4          5           3.12
```

**Result i want:**

`Runnum    Insitu  Runnum     Thickness             Date`

```
 2       1.23      2           2.32             1/9/2015

 3       2.32      3           2.21             1/9/2015

 4       2.21      4           3.12             1/8/2015
```

I want to join table1 and table2 and select the duplicate with the latest records,
this is my query so far.

```
SELECT a.Runnum, a.insitu, b.Runnum, b.thickness
FROM test.dummy_ease a
INNER JOIN (SELECT runnum, thickness, times FROM test.dummy_xrf group by runnum) AS b
ON a.runnum = b.runnum
```

The values returned from that query are almost right except for the duplicate value it is not returning the latest one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `ID` from table1 is set to auto_increment and the recent one is also based in this criteria then you have to self join table1 to the latest data

```
select a.Runnum,
b.insitu,
b.Runnum Runnumb, 
a.Thickness
from Table1 a
join (select max(ID) ID ,Runnum
      from Table1 
     group by Runnum) a1
using(ID,Runnum)
join Table2 b ON a.Runnum = b.Runnum
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2ac4/1)

If recent one depends on recent date criteria then in inner query you have to select max of your date column but from your sample data it looks like you have stored date as varchar type which will not be treated as date object you have to first convert it in to date object using `str_to_date` then calculate max of date and join your table1 again query will be something like [`Demo`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2ac4/6)

Comment: hello, my date column is stored as DATE type. and yes the ID's are auto increment,thank you for the suggestion! i will try it out!

Comment: also want to ask the usage of 'USING' @M Khalid

Comment: @ellabells if two table have some similar column names that will be used in join like pid in table1 and table2 then you can use `using(pid)` which is equal to `on(table1.pid = table2.pid)` its just only shortening the query part but you should use `on()` for best practice

Comment: ohh i see, okay. thank you for the tip. the query is working! @M khalid

Comment: wooops. i think we miss something, what if i exchange the value of

ID        Runnum    Thickness          Date

1          2           1.23             1/9/2015

2          2           2.32             1/8/2015

it is only returning the second one even if its not the latest record :( i need the latest record regardless of the ID :( @M Khalid Junaid

Comment: or is it okay to assume that the max(ID) will always be the latest entry? @M Khalid

Comment: @ellabells auto_increment purpose is it will auto generate for upcoming entries also also max(ID) will always be recent one in only one case if you are not trying to update this ID, also sample data in comment is not clear can you create sample demo of your data in sql as i have created

Comment: you are right, latest data will always have the max(ID). Sorry for the confusion, thank you very much for your insights! @M Khalid Junaid